# Accessing variables in a file from a class in other file

Tags: php, class, variables

If I have a config.php file with variables in it like so...

**config.php**:

```php
$cnf['dbhost'] = "0.0.0.0";
$cnf['dbuser'] = "mysqluser";
$cnf['dbpass'] = "mysqlpass";
```

How can I then access these variables from a class which is in another file, such as...

**inc/db.class.php**:

```php
class db() {

  function connect() {
    mysql_connect($cnf['dbhost'], $cnf['dbuser'], $cnf['dbpass']);
  }

}
$db = new db();
```

So, I can use the class in another file such as...

**index.php**:

```php
<html>
  <?php
    include('config.php');
    include('inc/db.class.php');
    $db->connect();
  ?>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include config file with [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), [require](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) or [require_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) at the beginning of your db script. You will also need to specify `$cnf` as global in the function you want to use, otherwise you cannot access global variables:

```
include "../config.php";

class db() {

  function connect() {
      global $cnf;
      mysql_connect($cnf['dbhost'], $cnf['dbuser'], $cnf['dbpass']);
  }

}
$db = new db();
```

**EDIT**:
On big project I prefer to use a boot.php where I include all the php files, so I wont need to include in every file everything I need. Having this, I just need to include the boot into the index.php and have to disposition all the definitions. It's slightly slower but really comfortable.

Comment: I just saw your edit and thats exactly what I'm trying to do. Is there any way I can include config.php in boot.php and still have the includes below access variables from config.php, without including them on each script?

Comment: This is very solution specific. But the straightforward solution would be to include every class declarations, arrays (like config, database requests and so forth, even the init script) into a boot php, and include boot into every standalone page. If every page is created from within index.php (e.g. calls like index.php?page=Home...) you only need to add boot to index. If you have multiple entry pages (e.g. home.php) you'll need to include boot to every one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Just include `config.php` in your `inc/db.class.php`.

**EDIT** (answering the query asked in comment)

What you could do is have a `init.php` like the following,

```
include('config.php');
include('db.class.php');
include('file.php');
```

So your classes will be able to access variables from `config.php`. And now for your `index.php` you only need to include `init.php` and all your classes, config, etc. will be included.

Comment: Thanks, I know this is possible but I have a file that loads lots of classes and functions called init.php - I was hoping I could include config.php before the other includes and they could access it without including config.php on every class / file. Possible?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, init.php is the file that has lots of classes and functions. So if you include config.php in that file and not in all individual class files, it should still work fine.

Comment: no, init.php is just a file that has lots of include('file.php')'s
If I can include config.php before the rest, how can they access the variables without including config.php on each script?

Comment: Yes, that's what I had already. Seems I just needed global $cnf in my classes. Thanks!!